# How do I make sure that at least one checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript

I am using checkboxes whose values is coming from database. Its name is same but name is fetching like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBankServices" name="<%=bs.getServiceID()%>">
<%=bs.getServiceDesc()%>
```

through this i am getting the values from the database.
Now i have to validate that at least one checkbox should be selected..

If any one  can help me i shall be thankful to u.
If i am giving like this the javascript code:

```
var services = document.getElementsById( 'chkBankServices' );
if(!(services[0].checked) && 
   !(services[1].checked) && 
   !(services[2].checked) && 
   !(services[3].checked) && 
   !(services[4].checked) && 
   !(services[5].checked) && 
   !(services[6].checked) &&
   !(services[7].checked) && 
   !(services[8].checked))
{ 
    alert( "Please select at least one service to submit." );
    return false;
}
```

It's not giving any alert message.
Is anything wrong in that.
Plz help me...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't mean to overwrite anyone else's edits. Just happened at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

in jQuery :

```
   alert(  $("#chkBankServices input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0 );
```

Comment: Just test for the first element e.g. if ($('selector')[0])

Comment: How can this modified to use a class name? I tried alert ($("$(this).attr('class'):checkbox:checked").length); but it doesnt work. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var services = document.getElementById( 'chkBankServices' );
var checkboxes = services.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checked = false;
for (var i=0,i0=checkboxes.length;i<i0;i++)
if (checkboxes[i].type.toLowerCase()=="checkbox")
{
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) checked = true;
}
```

and then:

```
if (!checked)
{
    alert('Not checked');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: did you forget to add a test to see if the checkbox is checked? looks like your setting checked to true as soon as you find a checkbox input control

Comment: thnks wilq.but tell me that what else i have to add in my html code.
this is my html code

<input type="checkbox" id="chkBankServices" name="<%=bs.getServiceID()%>"><%=bs.getServiceDesc()%>

Comment: where i have to add TagName.
plz help me

Comment: You dont have to name checkboxes at all - this solution I gave you just checks for any checkboxes that are inside chkBankServices element.

Comment: means i dont have to add anything in this
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBankServices" name="<%=bs.getServiceID()%>"><%=bs.getServiceDesc()%> 
but i use ur code it is not validating..means if i dont check on any checkbox and click on submit button ,it is submitting

Comment: Yes - mine code just sets flag "checked" - I added some lines for you there

Comment: but wilq its not working.its not rising any flag.
like i am giving like this

Comment: function validate(){
var services = document.getElementsById( 'chkBankServices' );
         var checkboxes = services.getElementsByTagName('input');
         var checked = false;
         for (var i=0,i0=checkboxes.length;i<i0;i++)
         if (checkboxes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase()=="checkbox")
         {
             if (checkboxes[i].checked) checked = true;
            
         }
         if (!checked)
         {
             alert('Not checked');
             return false;
         }

Comment: else{
          document.frmCustomerUpdation.cmd.value='btnUpdate';
          document.frmCustomerUpdation.submit();
         }
       
         }
and HTML is
***********
<td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" id="chkBankServices" name="<%=bs.getServiceID()%>" CHECKED><%= bs.getServiceDesc()%>

Comment: make sure that you use the version that I have right now,   look out for document.getElementById   and   that there should be  (.type) instead of (.nodeName)

Answer (score 4):

There is no getElementsById method, since there should only be one element with a given id. Perhaps you meant to use [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName)? This allows multiple elements to be returned.

As this is really a client side issue, it would help if you could post a sample of the generated HTML, and we can guide you further.

Comment: ok but how i can use getElementsByName becoz in my html code name is having 
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBankServices" name="<%=bs.getServiceID()%>"><%=bs.getServiceDesc()%>

Comment: @remish: Pay attention to the HTML the browser sees, not the template the server uses to generate it.

Comment: agreed - this is a client side issue, so it would help if you could post the HTML you are generating.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the rendered source to make sure your checkboxes are being given the expected names?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you with your specific problem, but your code would be easier to read if you avoided the massive if block and used a loop instead:

```
var checked = false;
for(var i=0;i<services.length;i++){
  if(services[i].checked){
    checked = true;
  }
}
if(!checked){
    alert( "Please select at least one service to submit." );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: wat the services will be taken here.if my html code is like this
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBankServices" name="<%=bs.getServiceID()%>"><%=bs.getServiceDesc()%>

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I'm betting you have that checkbox in a repeater of some sort and are creating multiple checkboxes with the same ID which is invalid html. I would wrap it in a div/span or something with an id like below:

```
 if (!isSomethingChecked()) {
    alert( "Please select at least one service to submit." );
    return false;
 }

  function isSomethingChecked() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("chkBankServices");
    for (var child in parent.childNodes) {
        var node = parent.childNodes[child];
        if (node && node.tagName === "INPUT" && node.checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

I assumed the HTML looks like :

```
<div id="chkBankServices">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox2" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox3" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox4" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox5" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox6" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox7" />
</div>
```

Comment: hi chad..i want to ask you something that how we can mention id as 1,2,and so on.coz my services is comming from database and i dont know how many services are available there.so tell me what i can do for this..

Comment: like in html we have given like this:
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBankServices" name="<%=bs.getServiceID()%>"><%=bs.getServiceDesc()%>
and in javascript
var services = document.getElementsById( 'chkBankServices' );
if(!(services[0].checked) && 
   !(services[1].checked) && 
   !(services[2].checked) && 
   !(services[3].checked) && 
   !(services[4].checked) && 
   !(services[5].checked) && 
   !(services[6].checked) &&
   !(services[7].checked) && 
   !(services[8].checked))
{ 
    alert( "Please select at least one service to submit." );
    return false;
}
so how i match

Comment: I don't know what that mess of code is, but I think my code is self explanatory. You are not giving enough information for people to help you.

Comment: ok i m giving you the whole code after that u tell what i have to do in dat so that i can check means alert msg should display if not a single checkbox is selected..

Comment: This is the HTML code
***************************
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBankServices" name="<%=bs.getServiceID()%>" CHECKED><%= bs.getServiceDesc()%>

Comment: *************Java Script cod***************
var services = document.getElementsById( 'chkBankServices' );
         
         if(!(services[0].checked) && !(services[1].checked) && !(services[2].checked) && !(services[3].checked)
         && !(services[4].checked) && !(services[5].checked) && !(services[6].checked) && !(services[7].checked)
         && !(services[8].checked))
        {   alert(  $("#chkBankServices input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0 );

         return false;
        }

Comment: else{
          document.frmCustomerUpdation.cmd.value='btnUpdate';
          document.frmCustomerUpdation.submit();
         }
       
         }

Now tell wat i have to add in HTML code and what in javascript
plz help me

Comment: Your html does not match your javascript, you have 9 checkboxes you are checking if they are checked, but your html only shows 1. Is it inside a <asp:Repeater> or something?